# enqueue multiple Google fonts with multiple weights and styles (italic)

Tags: php, functions

I am trying to enqueue multiple Google fonts with multiple weights (400,600,700, etc,) and styles (normal, italic) and can't figure out why it is not working.

This is the code that I am using in the functions.php:

```
function load_fonts() {
wp_register_style('googleFonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,600,700|Roboto:400,400italic,700,700italic');
wp_enqueue_style( 'googleFonts');
}
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'load_fonts');
```

This is the link that is being output in the source:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='googleFonts-css'  href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=+Dosis%3A400%2C600%2C700%7CRoboto%3A400%2C400italic%2C700%2C700italic&#038;ver=4.4.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I tested IOS devices at BrowsserStack and using the WhatFont browser extension and the WhatFont extension for Safari on an iPhone (worked well). It showed it using the fallback font-family Arial. I realized that this has something to do with the server (cheap shared hosted plan -- ugh!). What I am not quite sure, but I appreciate everyone's input

Any idea's?

Comment: I don't see much problem with this. so the url is encoded, why does it matters?

Comment: What isn't working? The multiple weights or the multiple fonts or both?

Comment: The correct fonts render in Firefox, Chrome, etc., but not on IOS devices. Does anyone have an good suggestion for cross browser compatibility tools to test on?

Comment: I tested IOS devices at BrowsserStack and using the WhatFont browser extension and the WhatFont extension for Safari on an iPhone (worked well). It showed it using the fallback font-family Arial. I realized that this has something to do with the server (cheap shared hosted plan -- ugh!). What I am not quite sure, but I appreciate everyone's input. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## Adding Multiple Google fonts in Wordpress Standard Way

```
 function adding_theme_css_js(){

    wp_enqueue_style("adding-google-fonts", all_google_fonts());

 }

 add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts","adding_theme_css_js");



 function all_google_fonts() {

    $fonts = array(

           "Open+Sans:400,300",
           "Raleway:400,600"

        );

    $fonts_collection = add_query_arg(array(

        "family"=>urlencode(implode("|",$fonts)),

        "subset"=>"latin"

        ),'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css');

    return $fonts_collection;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The default themes, TwentyXXXX, do it somewhat like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse217390_enqueue_google_fonts' );
function wpse217390_enqueue_google_fonts() {

 $query_args = array(
   'family' => 'Dosis:400,600,700|Roboto:400,400italic,700,700italic'
 );

 wp_register_style( 
   'google-fonts', 
   add_query_arg( $query_args, '//fonts.googleapis.com/css' ), 
   array(), 
   null 
 );
 wp_enqueue_style( 'google-fonts' );

}
```

Comment: This is more or less what I was doing, but I appreciate the tip to look at TwentyXXXX. I've been meaning to implement the method documented in the Codex for language translation and was happy to see that it's in 2016 if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 2):

A tidied/working answer based on Rubel Hossains answer above.... Add this to functions.php and update with the font names and weights you want.

```
    // Enqueue the fonts
    function add_fonts_to_theme(){
        wp_enqueue_style("adding-google-fonts", all_google_fonts());
     }
     add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts","add_fonts_to_theme");

    // Choose the fonts 
    function all_google_fonts() {
        $fonts = array(
               "Open+Sans:400,700",
               "Caveat:400,700",
               "Quicksand:400,700"
            );
        $fonts_collection = add_query_arg(array(
            "family"=>urlencode(implode("|",$fonts)),
            "subset"=>"latin"
            ),'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css');
        return $fonts_collection;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way to do this would be to use the [Google Webfonts Helper](http://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts) app. You select the typeface you want and then the weights/styles. It will then generate CSS and a .zip file for you to download and make these local fonts that you can then serve up yourself. This way you are not dependent on Google's servers or dealing with quirky URLs.

It is especially important if you plan to submit a theme to WordPress for hosting in their theme repository as your theme will be rejected if it is dependent on assets being loaded via CDN/etc. only without any local fallback anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Simple add to the end `, array(), null` like that:

```
function load_fonts() {
wp_register_style(
    'googleFonts', 
    'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,600,700|Roboto:400,400italic,700,700italic', 
    array(), 
    null
);
wp_enqueue_style( 'googleFonts');
}
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'load_fonts');
```

This solution ommit adding version to the end.